# @mention user should get immediate email

Tags: chatter

Is is possible to send immediate  chatter email notification to users which are @mentioned in the feeds/comments.
If yes then please let me know how?

Answer (score 2):

Each user can set their own chatter email preferences in "My Setting" -> Chatter -> Email Notifications. Then there is a subheading for "Mentions, Messages, or Endorsements" which has different elements that can be checked or unchecked.

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=collab_email_notify.htm&language=en_US

If the user is @mentioning themselves then they will not receive an email notification.

http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000097228&language=en_US

An example using the helper class: http://www.bridgefarmconsulting.com/blog/category/apex/

Comment: Thanks for reply, my question is can the user get the notification immediately or everyday once the user will all the chatter email notifications. currently, I am getting the email notifications but daily once  not the time when the chatter feed/comment is inserted with @mentioned.

Comment: They should get the notification immediately, are you inserting the "@mention" with a trigger and it's not happening immediately or is this when a user does it manually?

Comment: I am inserting "mention" using trigger. Also before insertion I am changing the Createdby in one of the scenario. When I do not change the createdby then the @mentioned user is getting the email immediately but when I change the createdby before insertion , then the "mentioned" user is not getting any notification.

Comment: Are you changing the created by to the same person being mentioned? If yes, @mention is designed not to email if you mention yourself.

Comment: I was able to get the immediate notification using the helper class and the 2 lines of code from that blog. I noticed you reposted your question, maybe post your code so they can look at what might be wrong.